# Querying for inactive users from a specific OU using powershell with the help of AD filter and LDAP filter

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to get the list of all inactive members from a specific OU named *inactive* with the following queries:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(OU=inactive,OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=companyname,DC=com)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))

(&(objectCategory=CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=companyname,DC=com)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(memberOf=OU=inactive,OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=companyname,DC=com)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))

(&(objectCategory=CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=companyname,DC=com)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:= OU=inactive,OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=companyname,DC=com))

(&(objectCategory=CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=companyname,DC=com)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:= OU=inactive,OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=companyname,DC=com))
```

However the search is not returning any record.

The CN for the inactive OU is `inactive/USERS/Administration/Companyname`.

Whenever I give this path for the inactive OU it does not return any results.

Please let me know how can we get the required results. When I try searching it from the AD console it shows the results as there are *1350* users inactive, but I am trying to incorporate it in a script.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Use powershell to return all the people in a specific OU?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to retrieve the members that are disabled in AD or not?

The disabled users in that ou:

```
Get-ADUser -Searchbase "OU=inactive,OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=companyname,DC=com" -LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
```

The not-disabled users in that ou:

```
Get-ADUser -Searchbase "OU=inactive,OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=companyname,DC=com" -LDAPFilter "(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
```

Edit: Even if you are not using the ActiveDirectory-module, the .Net-methods also supports the .searchBase in the form of .searchRoot, but then you would probably need the LDAPfilter:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
```